# Azure devops extension postinstall page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

We are building an extension on azure devops board to capture time and on submit we need to sent the details to our endpoint for business use case. After the successful install of the azure devops plugin to company, we need to direct the users to our domain for reading the consent and authorize it. When the app is installed, we are getting the post request with the installed details. But since its a post request, i can't redirect the users to browser for authorization with our end point.. so, i am looking for adding a button on the install success page(attached the screenshot of it), so that user can click and authorize it after install, but i couldn't find any option for that. Can some one guide me on this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to extend or integrate into that workflow. My recommendation would be to add a tab in the organization settings of the Azure DevOps organization and have the user authorize and consent.

Comment: Sure, thank you.. yeah, we are planning to go in that route

Comment: I guess every user has to consent before using the extension? Then I would build that into the boards extension itself.